# CakePHP Filter Search

Tags: cakephp

I need to build a filter search that returns data using the criteria set.
My problem is building the search. It needs to be a OR query because anyone of them could be selected.

http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/2527/screenshot20100118at095.png

This is what will be searched.

Accommodation.space
Accommodation.room_type
Accommodation.facilities
Accommodation.speaks

The only way I can think of doing it is an if statement for each input, but that would be 15 if statements, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

`$Model->postConditions($this->data)` [[reference](http://book.cakephp.org/view/432/postConditions)] can do this for you.

It will auto-generate Cake compatable conditions array, and you can even specify if you want it to be an `"AND/OR"` operation

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice component which could likely be tweaked to work for you. It might even work right "out of the box"

http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/cakephp_filter_component/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new tutorial about this. Might help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAVuLXFVaCw